# BeautifulSoup Python get an element called "title"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have the following HTML:

`<span title="总播放数236819" class="view">23.7万播放&nbsp;·&nbsp;</span>`

and I just want the '236819' from this.

I have the BeautifulSoup object created and the code:

`views = soup.findAll('span', class_ = 'view')`

How do I add to this/remove from this to get the bit that I'm after?

Thank you!

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry.  Shall I delete this query?

Comment: Nah, its okay. Getting a question marked as duplicate is not necessarily a bad thing, as you might not have found that answer in your research. Next time, try searching it up on google or stack overflow first, and then ask your question (this was the first google search result to "beautifulsoup get title attribute")

Comment: Oof, that's embarrassing.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example `re` module to extract only digits from `"title"` attibute:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = (
    """<span title="总播放数236819" class="view">23.7万播放&nbsp;·&nbsp;</span>"""
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

views = soup.findAll("span", class_="view")

for view in views:
    print("".join(re.findall(r"\d+", view["title"])))   # <-- find only digits in "title" attribute
```

Prints:

```
236819
```